# Does anybody know how to launch the print dialog from chrome by selenium+python

Tags: python, selenium, printing, selenium-webdriver

I have a question about how to launch the print dialog from chrome browser. I know the shortcut key to open this is ctrl+p, but I don't know how to describe it in selenium. Does anyone know this? Thanks a lot!

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work on my Chrome browser.

```
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'))
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('T').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: if there is no way to do this, does any one know how to open the right button menu from a webpage by using selenium+python+chrome

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to trigger the JavaScript function that triggers the print pop-up. That function is `window.print()`.

So what you need is to trigger that function after arriving at the page you want to print.
So say you want to print the front page of [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
# now you're at the page you want to print. Trigger print function
driver.execute_path("window.print()")
```

Now it should prompt you to the print pop-up. The reason you need to trigger the JavaScript function is because JavaScript is the browser's language.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are asking about, but this is what worked for me in `Firefox`.

Send `CTRL+P` (or `COMMAND+P` on mac) to the `body` element using [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'))
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('p').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: yes, I want to do the same thing on Chrome, just want to open the print dialog from chrome, it seems your method doesn't work on Chrome browser. Is there any way to launch the print dialog from Chrome browser. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sansha I edited my original answer. It should give you what you need now. Take a look.

Answer (score -2):

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")

driver.execute_script("window.print()")
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.